# Cross-domain REST proxy with Javascript, HTML5

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, iframe, postmessage

I'm writing a service (say, service.com) that provides a **REST API** to external apps running inside of **IFrames**. (These apps are hosted from domains outside the service.com).

I'm planning a javascript **client library** for the apps to make pure-javascript requests to the service.com REST API -- basically using **postMessage** and some ad-hoc encapsulation of my API calls to get messages back and forth across frames (from the outside-app.com IFrame --> service.com REST API, and back to the IFrame with a response).

***My question***:  is there any robust, **general-purpose javascript** library to accomplish the kind of cross-domain REST request proxying I need, or **should I just hack it from scratch?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you heard about [origin access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control)?  You can just set it in your .htaccess to allow XHR requests across domains.

```
Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

In which case, you don't need anything past your standard AJAX components.

Comment: what is .htaccess and how can I set it? Can u explain it?